# How do I remove an array from an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am attempting to write a function that iterates over a given object(obj). Each time it comes across an array within the object, it removes the array. The code seems appropriate, but please tell me what I'm missing:

```
function removeArrayValues(obj) {

  for (isKeyAnArray in obj) {
     if (typeof obj[isKeyAnArray] === 'array') {
       delete obj[isKeyAnArray];
    }
  }
}

var obj = {
  a: [1, 3, 4],
  b: 2,
  c: ['hi', 'there']
}

removeArrayValues(obj);
console.log(obj); // --> { b: 2 }
```

Comment: Only arrays are delete {b:2} is not an  array.  Include this case in your function

Comment: Consider returning a new object with the non-array elements as an alternative to modifying the object that is passed in.

Answer (score 2):

`typeof` returns `"object"` for an array. You can use `Array.isArray()` to check if the property is an array.

Here is the modified version of your code:

```
function removeArrayValues(obj) {

  for (isKeyAnArray in obj) {
     if (Array.isArray(obj[isKeyAnArray])) {
       delete obj[isKeyAnArray];
    }
  }
}

var obj = {
  a: [1, 3, 4],
  b: 2,
  c: ['hi', 'there']
}

removeArrayValues(obj);
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

check if it is an array is another way. In the included code sample 2 variations are shown.

```js
function removeArrayValues(obj) {

  for (isKeyAnArray in obj) {
     if (obj[isKeyAnArray] instanceof Array){
       console.log("instanceof array true");
       delete obj[isKeyAnArray];
     }
     if (Array.isArray(obj[isKeyAnArray])){
       console.log("isArray true");
       delete obj[isKeyAnArray];
     }
     console.log(typeof obj[isKeyAnArray]);
     if (typeof obj[isKeyAnArray] === 'array') {
       delete obj[isKeyAnArray];
    }
  }
}

var obj = {
  a: [1, 3, 4],
  b: 2,
  c: ['hi', 'there']
}

removeArrayValues(obj);
console.log(obj); // --> { b: 2 }
document.getElementById("exampleText").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

```html
<p id="exampleText"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Gokhan Sari 's way of doing is exactly accurate. This is more of an add-on if you wanted to go the es6 or just hipster route :D

```
const removeArrayValues = obj => Object.entries(obj).forEach(val => Array.isArray(val[1]) && delete obj[val[0]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that this would not mutate the original object (just add as alternative answer in case it could help):

```
const newObj = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(obj).filter(([, value]) => !Array.isArray(value))
)

console.log(newObj);
```